# How to read files in folders?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get my application to check for folders in the folderbrowserdialogs selectedpath and then get those files, but it doesn't work I have tried both listed ways below. The second way gives me an error: (Expression is of type `char` which is not a collection type)

```
    For Each folder In FileBrowserDialog.SelectedPath
        Dim counter As  _
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
            counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(folder)
            Label1.Text = counter.Count.ToString
        Next



For Each folder In FileBrowserDialog.SelectedPath
        Dim counter As  _
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
For Each foundfile In folder
            counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(foundfile)
            Label1.Text = counter.Count.ToString
        Next
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `FileBrowserDialog.SelectedPath` will give you the path, not the files *in* the path/folder

Comment: As @Plutonix says, FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath returns a single string. When you treat the string as a collection as in `For Each folder In FileBrowserDialog.SelectedPath` the string is treated as an array of Char and folder will be a single Char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath` will return the path the user selected in the dialog.  You still need to write code to go get the files.  There may not be a need to get the folders and then files in them. Net has ways to do that for you:

```
FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
Dim myPath As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath

' get all files for a folder
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(myPath)

' get all files for all sub folders
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*.*",
         System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

' get certain file types for folder and subs
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*.jpg",
         System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

---

You also are not going to be able to simply assign the results to a `ReadOnlyCollection` like that, because they are ReadOnly.  The collection needs to be created/instanced with the complete list:

```
Dim counter As new ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)(files)
```